# MySQL Cannot join columns from different database having different data type

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sqldatatypes

I have two tables in different tables in different database.

Database 1, Table 1:

```
Name | Data Type | Collation

id     BINARY      
count  INT(5)
```

Example:

```
id                 count             
1caf69a993367281   3
```

Database 2, Table 1

```
Name | Data Type | Collation  
id     VARCHAR     latin1_swedish_ci    
id2    INT(10)
```

Example:

```
id                 id2
1caf69a993367281   344
```

I need to do something like this

```
SELECT id, id2, count 
 FROM `Database 1`.`Table 1` 
 INNER JOIN `Database 2`.`Table 1` 
 USING(`id`)
```

Also, the id is stored as hex value (eg. 1caf69a993367281).
Database 1 is created by an open source tool (Piwik, to be precise), and states that, "To fetch id from Table 1, you can use CONV(HEX(`id`) 16, 10) to fetch its decimal value.

For convenience, I've tried

```
SELECT id, id2, count 
 FROM `Database 1`.`Table 1` 
 INNER JOIN `Database 2`.`Table 1` 
 ON CONV(HEX(`Database 1`.`Table 1`.`id`), 16, 10) = CONV(HEX(`Database 2`.`Table 1`.`id`), 16, 10)
```

Both of these queries are giving empty results.

Comment: you're converting BOTH tables' values, but it sounds like only the table from plix needs converting. you probably want `join ... on yourtable.id = conv(plixtable.id ....)` instead.

Comment: both tables are saving same value. i.e., something like "1caf69a993367281". Only difference is that Table 1 has the column declared as BINARY. Now I'm not sure whether it could be the reason for empty results.

Comment: binary is the equivalent of varchar, but is exempt from character sets and charset translation rules. what you put in is what you get out. it's highly unlikely that your swedish collation on the varchar would change a string, since 0-9a-f isn't exactly "foreign".

Comment: @MarcB Edited the question for your clarity.

Comment: If they are already both HEX, i see no point converting to decimal.  did you try `CAST(Database 1.Table 1.id AS CHAR) = Database 2.Table 1.id` ?

Comment: @MarcB, yeah Charset is not affecting, that part I am now sure of. But something is stopping these columns from getting compared properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently we need to explicitly specify the Datatype everywhere we mention the column. Especially at Binary data type columns.
Something like this worked-

```
SELECT HEX(id), id2, count 
 FROM `Database 1`.`Table 1` a
 INNER JOIN `Database 2`.`Table 1` b
ON BINARY HEX(`a`.id) = BINARY UPPER(`b`.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are already HEX and just the type is different, then I think this may do it

```
SELECT id, id2, count 
 FROM `Database 1`.`Table 1` 
 INNER JOIN `Database 2`.`Table 1` 
 ON CAST(`Database 1`.`Table 1`.`id` AS CHAR) = `Database 2`.`Table 1`.`id`
```

Comment: Hi, tried it. Still negative. Also for clarity, I tried `SELECT * FROM Table 1 WHERE id = 'd5f835dda749d37f'`, with and without CAST. Both give empty result.
Even `CAST(HEX(id), 16, 10) = '18446744073709551615'` won't give any result.

Comment: it sounds like that id doesn't exist in that table.  are you sure it does?  Start with one that's really there.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the id. Its there in both tables. Any chance that this is some other problem ?